# What are the various container states in the ContainerInventory table for data collected by Azure Monitor for Containers

Tags: monitoring, monitor, azure-aks, azure-monitoring

I have enabled Azure Monitor for Containers from the AKS Insights blade. In the Log Analytics workspace where the data ends up, I see a table called ContainerInventory. Does this table contain container information for all containers including stopped containers or does it only contain the containers that are up and running?

Comment: For the information of stopped container, what do you mean? the container is always stopped or running for a while then stopped, after enable azure monitor?

Answer (score 0):

As per this [issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/24338#issuecomment-461005463):

> If container is stopped, monitoring will continue but there will be no
> data.

Hope it helps.